# Running task process ID

Tags: android

Can i get process ID for running task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if this gives you the information you need: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how do you want it. If you want it via adb then use, adb shell; ps command

Comment: Thanks Vinoth. I want PS ID in my java program.

Answer (score 1):

I will use getTaskId() method in first activity on my application.